# unload a sound in AIR, system memory getting full

Tags: javascript, audio, air

I'm building an AIR application which loads and plays mp3's from a users computer, I'm using the code pretty much straight out the book to do this:

```
function startTrack()
{
    if (isStarted == 0)
    {
        theSound = new air.Sound();
        urlReq  = new air.URLRequest(...dynamicaly generated extension);
        theSound.load(urlReq);
        soundHandle = theSound.play();
        isStarted = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        soundHandle.stop();
        soundHandle = null;
        theSound = null;
        urlReq = null;
        isStarted = 0;
        startTrack();
    }
}
```

There are a series of links on the page of the app which play different mp3's, when you click on one it passes the path of the sound to `urlReq` and plays it. When you click on a second sound it stops the first playing and plays the next one. What I thought would happen is the old sound would be destroyed by call `theSound = null` etc but it just seems to stop the sound play the new sound and keep the old one loaded so you eventually run out of system memory after lots of tracks have been started and kept loaded.

So if anyone knows how to unload a sound or how to generally dump things from the system memory the app is using it would be much appreciated.

Thanks all

Will

Answer (score 0):

You call air.System.gc() after deleting all the related elements.